# Setting Up a Poap Booth to Give Out tokens at a decentraland event

Tags: decentraland

Hey I am tryng to create a poap-booth for my event on decentraland.

Using the following documentation I am linking the booth in the game.ts SDK to the poapHandler.ts

This would allow me to create a token to give out at events when connected to the POAPBOOTH entity

I need help as to connect to firebase using cloudfirestore which is used to store addresses and give out the token I need to set up two api endpoints using postman

https://github.com/decentraland-scenes/POAP-Booth

https://decentraland.org/blog/tutorials/servers-part-2/

the GET function works with a success message of 200

However the POST method for signatures does not with 500 error

Comment: Did you find an example of the Server side code for the POAP dispenser?  I found the server side code for the Guestbook https://github.com/decentraland-scenes/Guest-Book-API but not for the POAP booth.